# MethodBase Object of async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reflection, methodbase

in my application i have a little action log. In there I save the last few calls of certain methods in my application like this:

```
saveLastAction(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), getCurrentStatus(), item, /*loadFresh*/ false);
```

It allows me to navigate and refresh through my last actions

```
    public void Refresh(bool loadFresh = true)
    {
        if (!isInitialized) return;

        try
        {
            lastStatus = getCurrentStatus();

            var parameters = lastActionsParameters.Pop();
            var method = lastActions.Pop();

            //Set the load Fresh parameter to True
            parameters[method.GetParameters().First(pi => pi.Name == "loadFresh").Position] = loadFresh;

            //Invoke the Method again with the adopted parameters
            method.Invoke(this, parameters);

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I worked perfectly until i changed one of the methods which calls saveLastAction to async. Since then `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` only returns the MoveNext function and not the actual function i called.

Is there a way to get to the actual MethodBase Object of the called function, whether at the time of saving or calling doesn't matter.

Best regards
lolsharp

Comment: The info you provided is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

I created a little help function:

```
private MethodInfo getMethodBase(object caller, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = "")
    {
        //Binding Flags to include private functions
        return caller.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    }
```

Using the CallerMemberNameAttribute directly didn't work because I was also using params parameter. In the end a very similar to Peters approach.

Comment: I was trying to find an alternative as the questioner, and this worked wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the `MethodBase` object? Or is it sufficient to just log enough detail that a human can figure out which method it was?

If the latter, then it's fairly simple: note that the method that is executing, is actually contained in a compiler-generated class where the class name itself contains the name of the method the compiler rewrote to generate that class.

So in your `saveLastAction()` method, where presumably you log the `MethodBase.Name` property value, you should first check the `MethodBase.DeclaringType.Name` value, and if it looks like `<SomeMethodName>d_5` (where the specifics after the closing angle bracket may vary as well), you can use the text within the angle brackets for the method name instead of the `MethodBase.Name` property value.

Note that only the compiler is allowed to generate class names with those angle brackets, so you don't have to worry about getting a false positive.

As an added bonus, this will allow your logging code to work with iterator methods too. :)

If you need the `MethodBase` object itself, that's a bit more complicated, but would follow the same basic strategy. Get the method name, and then look that method up in the `MethodBase.DeclaringType.DeclaringType` type (i.e. the type that contains the compiler-generated type). Note that if there is more than one overload for the method, identifying the specific overload that was used may be tricky or impractical.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to a get a whole lot easier in [C#7 using local functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

```
public Task DoAThingAsync()
{
    var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    LogMethod(method);

    return doWork();

    // Define inner function to actually do the work
    async Task doWork()
    {
         // Do the work here
    }
}
```

You can already achieve this with anonymous methods or delegates but this makes the code it very clearn.